# how to split a string without any special characters ,uppercase or numbers in a word

Tags: python, string

I need to split this word into a sentence using python.Is there any way to do this??

```
   strng = 'thisisastring'
```

o/p:

```
this is a string
```

Comment: Not really, there certainly isn't any functionality for this built into python. I guess you could have a dictionary text file and try to find words in the string.

Comment: This is non-trivial in general. Ask yourself what the result of `projectorlight` should be. Is it `projector light` or `project or light`? You can no-doubt find more (and more clever) examples without much effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter and Mark have already pointed out, this is a hard problem with no easy or unique solution.  You certainly need a list of possible words to start with.  Probably your best bet is then to use backtracking.

Here's a simple function that returns a list of tuples, where each tuple represents one possible sentence.

```py
words = [
  "a", "as", "is", "light", "or", "project", 
  "projector", "string", "the", "this"
]

def findPhrase(text):
    result = []
    for word in words:
        if text == word:
            # if the entire text is the word, there is no need
            # to look at the (now empty) rest.
            result.append((word,))
        elif text.startswith(word):
            # if the text starts with the current word, try to 
            # find all partitions of the remaining text
            rest = findPhrase(text[len(word):])

            # if there are any such partitions, add them all to our
            # list of results, and put the current word in front
            # of each of these solutions
            for solution in rest:
                result.append((word,) + solution)
    return result
```

Note that I use `(word,)` in this code to make it a tuple, so we can simply add it together, i.e. `("is",) + ("a", "string") -> ("is", "a", "string")`.

The basic idea of the algorithm is to split the string one word at a time.  So, a first approximation would be the following, which takes the first word that might fit and then tries to split the rest of the string.

```py
def my_split(text):
    if text == "":
        return []
    for word in words:
        if text.startswith(word):
            rest = text[len(word):]
            result = [word] + my_split(rest)
            return result
```

However, this does not work in general.  In your example, once you reach the rest being `"astring"`, the algorithm might then try `"as"` as the next possible word, but because `"tring"` is not a word, it simply fails.

Comment: Great!! That looks amazing